# SVN conflict (mc) and (tc) specific example

Tags: svn

So bob and alice are working on a file and they run into conflict here. Im wondering what the -1,7,1,15 mean. The +<<<<.mine sign, and the +>>>>>.r sign. How would the answers be different if Alice and Bob ran (mc) for each, and how did you find the answer out(without running it)? The file is below.

```
@@ -1,7 +1,15 @@
This is going to be tricky.
-
+Yes, it will be.
It really will be.
+<<<<<<< .mine 
+Bob tried to fix the file.
I'm sure.
+=======
+Alice is changing much.
+I'm sure of that.
+>>>>>>> .r[??]
+:( - what happened?

+Best of luck!

-Best of luck!
+This is a mess.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alice and Bob edit the same area of the same file. Alice commits her changes - everything is fine.

Bob attempts to commit his changes and the conflict is identified. There is no conflict from Alice's point of view as she committed her changes first.

It is only Bob that has to choose between accepting Alice's changes and discarding his own (tc) - or discarding Alice's changes by overwriting them with his own (mc) - or some other action.

See a version of the manual [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html).